# Accordion in Faq?

Tags: magento2.2

I have ORDER ,MYACCOUNT FAQ Category .
Now Account category is open state and then ORDER is closed state.
How to close ACCOUNT category,if i have click ORDER category .

```
<?php
    $collectionTitle = $this->getCollectionFaqcat();
    ?>
    <div id="element" data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active":[0], "multipleCollapsible": true}}'> 
        <?php foreach ($collectionTitle as $item): ?>  
            <div data-role="collapsible">
                <div data-role="trigger"> 
                    <span>
                        <?php echo $block->filterOutputHtml($item->getCategoryName()); ?>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>    

            <?php $collection = $this->getCollectionFaq($item->getId()); ?> 
            <div data-role="content">
                <?php foreach ($collection as $items): ?>             
                    <?php echo $block->filterOutputHtml($items->getQuestion()); ?> 
                    <?php echo $block->filterOutputHtml($items->getAnswer()); ?>            
                <?php endforeach; ?> 
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open only one accordion at once and close the one in active state while opening other you have to change `multipleCollapsible": true` To `multipleCollapsible": false`